# Sum of submatrices of bigger matrix

Tags: c++, c, matrix, submatrix

I have a big matrix as input, and I have the size of a smaller matrix. I have to compute the sum of all possible smaller matrices which can be formed out of the bigger matrix.

Example.
Input matrix size: 4 × 4

Matrix:

```
1 2 3 4
5 6 7 8
9 9 0 0
0 0 9 9
```

Input smaller matrix size: 3 × 3 (not necessarily a square)

Smaller matrices possible:

```
1 2 3
5 6 7
9 9 0

5 6 7
9 9 0
0 0 9

2 3 4
6 7 8
9 0 0

6 7 8
9 0 0
0 9 9
```

Their sum, final output

```
14 18 22
29 22 15
18 18 18
```

I did this:

```
int** matrix_sum(int **M, int n, int r, int c)
{
    int **res = new int*[r];
    for(int i=0 ; i<r ; i++) {
        res[i] = new int[c];
        memset(res[i], 0, sizeof(int)*c);
    }

    for(int i=0 ; i<=n-r ; i++)
    for(int j=0 ; j<=n-c ; j++)
    for(int k=i ; k<i+r ; k++)
    for(int l=j ; l<j+c ; l++)
    res[k-i][l-j] += M[k][l];

    return res;
}
```

I guess this is too slow, can anyone please suggest a faster way?

Comment: What is the point of `int** M`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your current algorithm is O((m - p) * (n - q) * p * q). The worst case is when p = m / 2 and q = n / 2.

The algorithm I'm going to describe will be O(m * n + p * q), which will be O(m * n) regardless of p and q.

The algorithm consists of 2 steps.

Let the input matrix A's size be `m x n` and the size of the *window* matrix being `p x q`.

First, you will create a precomputed matrix B of the same size as the input matrix. Each element of the precomputed matrix B contains the sum of all the elements in the sub-matrix, whose top-left element is at coordinate (1, 1) of the original matrix, and the bottom-right element is at the same coordinate as the element that we are computing.

```
B[i, j] = Sum[k = 1..i, l = 1..j]( A[k, l] ) for all 1 <= i <= m, 1 <= j <= n
```

This can be done in O(m * n), by using this relation to compute each element in O(1):

```
B[i, j] = B[i - 1, j] + Sum[k = 1..j-1]( A[i, k] ) + A[j] for all 2 <= i <= m, 1 <= j <= n
```

`B[i - 1, j]`, which is everything of the sub-matrix we are computing except the current row, has been computed previously. You keep a prefix sum of the current row, so that you can use it to quickly compute the sum of the current row.

This is another way to compute `B[i, j]` in O(1), using the property of the 2D prefix sum:

```
B[i, j] = B[i - 1, j] + B[i, j - 1] - B[i - 1, j - 1] + A[j] for all 1 <= i <= m, 1 <= j <= n and invalid entry = 0
```

Then, the second step is to compute the result matrix S whose size is `p x q`. If you make some observation, S[i, j] is the sum of all elements in the matrix size (m - p + 1) * (n - q + 1), whose top-left coordinate is (i, j) and bottom-right is (i + m - p + 1, j + n - q + 1).

Using the precomputed matrix B, you can compute the sum of any sub-matrix in O(1). Apply this to compute the result matrix S:

```
SubMatrixSum(top-left = (x1, y1), bottom-right = (x2, y2))
     = B[x2, y2] - B[x1 - 1, y2] - B[x2, y1 - 1] + B[x1 - 1, y1 - 1]
```

Therefore, the complexity of the second step will be O(p * q).

The final complexity is as mentioned above, O(m * n), since p <= m and q <= n.

Comment: and after implementing that, you can check your algorithm in this problem http://acm.timus.ru/problem.aspx?space=1&num=1146